# Statistics dropped when an Object is dropped?

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

If an object (table/indexes..) is dropped, will the statistics related to that object be still available or gets dropped along with the object that is dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From virtual-dba.com*

> Just Note when Dropping a Table/Indexes: If any statistic types are
>   associated with the table, then the database disassociates the
>   statistics types and removes any user-defined statistics collected
>   with the statistics type.

Comment: What about auto created statistics (begin with _WA*)? do they continue to exist? reason for this question is if a table gets created & dropped daily, will the older auto created statistics be still in use? Thank you..

Comment: This is only for manually created statistics. Dropping tables and/or indexes drops User Created Stats. Yours are ok. They become problematic sometimes and outdated: `Since auto-stats are created implicitly and quietly behind the scenes, most DBAs are unaware of how many really exist. For every query that any client ever issued against the database, there may be a remaining statistics object created just for it. Even if it was a test query, issued once many years ago and never again. Auto Statistics objects are persistent and will remain in the database forever until explicitly dropped.`

Answer (score -1):

What is default trace?

> The default trace is a new feature first included with SQL Server 2005 which provides auditing on schema modifications such as table creation and stored procedure deletion and the like. It does run by default, but you can turn it on ..

For more info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1739/using-the-default-trace-in-sql-server/

In this query.. use `EventClass` 92 and 93 to track database auto-growth events. Here is the query to find who dropped / created or altered object in database or database itself.

```
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @start VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @indx INT;

SELECT @current = path
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1;

SET @current = REVERSE(@current)

SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', @current)

SET @current = REVERSE(@current)
SET @start = LEFT(@current, LEN(@current) - @indx) + '\log.trc';

-- Change filter as needed
SELECT 
    CASE EventClass
       WHEN 46 THEN 'Object:Created'
       WHEN 47 THEN 'Object:Deleted'
       WHEN 164 THEN 'Object:Altered'
    END, 
    DatabaseName, ObjectName, HostName, ApplicationName, LoginName, 
    StartTime
FROM
    ::fn_trace_gettable(@start, DEFAULT)
WHERE 
    EventClass IN (46,47,164) AND EventSubclass = 0 AND DatabaseID <> 2
ORDER BY 
    StartTime DESC
```

You can use this query for finding all details of created, deleted, alter table info...

Here some different default trace in SQL Server....

```
SELECT DISTINCT Trace.EventID, TraceEvents.NAME AS Event_Desc
FROM ::fn_trace_geteventinfo(1) Trace,
     sys.trace_events TraceEvents
WHERE Trace.eventID = TraceEvents.trace_event_id
```

This above query is used for Event Class and also in above example using (Object:Created, Object:Deleted, Object:Altered); you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: So does that actually answer the question? From reading the question it seemed to me the answer would be Yes or No?

Comment: In above Exmple... i'm showing statics of alter,delete..table...history

Comment: OP is asking about the database [statistics objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-2017), not statistics on doing stuff...